# chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab allways failed until I click the popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab() allways return failed message, until I click the popup.

and in background's error message , it said :

Error: Either the '<all_urls>' or 'activeTab' permission is required.

actually , I did add 'activeTab' permission.

The weird thing is, once  after clicking the popup page, everything works well.

content_script.js:

```js
let btn = document.createElement("button")
btn.innerText="screen cap"
document.body.appendChild(btn)

btn.onclick=(e)=>{
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({purpose:"screenCap"})
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg)=>{
    if(msg.purpose  && msg.purpose==="screenCap" ){
        if(msg.status) {
            console.log(msg.data)
        }
        else{
            console.log("screen cap failed")
        }
    }
})
```

background.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
(msg)=>{
if(msg.purpose && msg.purpose === "screenCap"){
   chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab().then(
(data)=>{  }
)
}
}
)
```

manifest.json

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "screen cap test",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "action": { "default_popup": "popup.html" },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": [
            "content.js"
        ],
        "matches": [
            "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
        ]
    }],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js",
        "persistent": true
    },

    "externally_connectable": {
        "matches": ["*://*.google.com/*"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "notifications",
        "storage"
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [{
        "matches": [
            "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "resources": [
            "**/*",
            "*"
        ],
        "use_dynamic_url": true
    }]
}
```

popup.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>hello world</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

[download runable code sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1apI2IQmVy8Q8j2n3RlXn2_UY5vywnHs1/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Might be related to this unresolved bug: https://shorturl.at/pquR8

Answer (score -2):

Having the "activeTab" permission does not mean that an extension automatically receives temporary host permission for the currently active tab.

The user must also invoke the extension, by doing one of the following:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/activeTab/#invoking-activeTab

- Executing an action
- Executing a context menu item
- Executing a keyboard shortcut from the commands API
- Accepting a suggestion from the omnibox API

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/activeTab/

> The activeTab permission gives an extension temporary access to the
> currently active tab when the user invokes the extension - for example
> by clicking its action. Access to the tab lasts while the user is on
> that page, and is revoked when the user navigates away or closes the
> tab.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#perms

> The "activeTab" permission
>
> activeTab grants an extension temporary host permission for the
> current tab in response to a user invocation. Unlike host permissions,
> activeTab does not trigger any warnings.